# SQL DB connection in blue prism

Tags: sql-server, spy

I am trying to execute simple sql query like select *.. in blue prism.I have connected to DB using 'set connection' from 'BPA Object - Data - SQL Server' file in VBO. Now when I execute a query or when I use get rows affected in action, I am not getting desired output.
Kindly guide me if there is another way or I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use Data – OLEDB object. You need to use following actions:

- Set Connection - You can use only “Connection” input – see more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
- Open
- Get Collection – Input: SQL – text item with query, Output: Results - Collection
- Close